# Coin change problem - Using Memoization - not working

Tags: python-3.x, memoization, coin-change

The coin change problem- trying to get the maximum number of options to make change.
So- wrote a code using memoization, but it's working only until n=980. But when i'm trying to take a larger n python stop running due to- "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison".

How can i fix it?

```
def find_num_changes_mem(n, lst, memo=None):
if n==0:
    return 1
if n<0 or lst==[]:
    return 0
if memo==None:
    memo={}
if (n,len(lst)) in memo:
    return memo[(n,len(lst))]
else:
    if lst[0]>n:
        memo[(n,len(lst))]=find_num_changes_mem(n,lst[1:],memo)
    else:
        memo[(n,len(lst))]=find_num_changes_mem(n-lst[0],lst[0:],memo)+find_num_changes_mem(n,lst[(1):],memo)
return memo[(n,len(lst))]
```

Comment: I've tried to check to options in that case- the first is to keep and subtract the same number for situations like (1,1,1,1) as change. (that is why calling the lst[0:]), the other one is ignoring that option and call it from lst[1:]..

Comment: The recursion limit is 1000 by default; if you need to recurse more times than that, you can call the `sys.setrecursionlimit` function. Otherwise, you'll need to refactor to a non-recursive implementation. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit

Comment: it's homework, so i have to use memoization and recursion and cannot import any library..

Comment: Then you will need to radically redesign your solution, because you aren't going to be able to make recursive calls at a depth of more than 1000. You can write a divide-and-conquer algorithm which works by splitting the list in half, and doing recursive calls on each half, for O(log m) recursion depth instead of O(m) where the list length is m. There is unlikely to be a benefit from memoizing that solution, though, perhaps it is not what your instructor intended; try asking them about the maximum recursion limit if your program is supposed to work for lists longer than 1000.